# Alternate accounts of users previously suspended(though not currently under suspension)

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension

Well, I was unable to find a relevant question concerning such a possibility, so here's mine;

Bar any 'invisible' blocks on an account(such as preventing a user for asking/answering questions), I guess I'm wondering if there are any flags on an account that was (in the past) repeatedly suspended for voting irregularities.. and if so, what the rules are on the owner of that account, creating a new account.

If the above paragraph is not clear, here's another attempt in a different way:

1. User A commits vote fraud with their sock account.
2. User A gets suspended.
3. After suspension period is over, User A again commits vote fraud with another account.
4. User A again get suspended.
5. Fast forward six months, User A creates a new account, and begins contributing(<s>no fraud detected thus far</s>I take that back, fraud detected).

That in mind, is this sort of thing allowed?  I feel that it shouldn't be, due to any history that may be tied to the account that was committing the vote fraud, but then, I also don't know how these things work.  If this is a duplicate, I apologize.  <s>There is also a specific case in mind here, but to avoid shaming, I won't link accounts.</s>(due to the fact that it is appears vote fraud is occurring, see below for the relevant accounts)  If it turns out this sort of thing *isn't* allowed, I'll flag the account for a moderator.

There now appears to be vote fraud again occurring, so, here are the accounts

- **New:** https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357279/dummy-code?tab=reputation
- **Old:** https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379592/dummy-code?tab=reputation

The old account was suspended two or three times due to vote fraud, and now it seems, the new account is doing the same thing.

Comment: Vote fraud is fraud no matter who does it or where it occurs. If you're suspicious of something, feel free to flag one of the user's posts - a moderator will look into it.

Comment: @Emracool Flagged.  I'm rather disappointed that this guy is doing this again.  Instead of using it as a fresh start, they've just fallen to their old habits.

Comment: Oh golly, if it isn't our old friend Dummy Code.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Have they popped up more often than I was aware?  I only know of the old account, and the two-three times it was suspended.

Comment: Let's just say he doesn't seem intent on making amends at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Emracool said:

> Vote fraud is fraud no matter who does it or where it occurs. If you're suspicious of something, feel free to flag one of the user's posts - a moderator will look into it.

Whether it is a case of repeated offenses, or someone falling back to their old ways, or a new case entirely, vote fraud is still vote fraud; we will look at every case and handle it accordingly. Your best course of action, as a community member, is to flag the offending posts/accounts to raise them to us.

Comment: Guess you know: the new account is now suspended, and some puppet was removed, but still [quite a few very suspicious votes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VcfQZ.png) from two other users remain?

Comment: @Arjan: There's a "-210 User was removed" entry - I'm not sure but perhaps votes from deleted users remain in someone's rep history and are covered by that user removal entry.

Comment: Ah, that might be true! (Also, I don't really care, just wanted to make sure moderators and the team know it.)